# check the checked property of a checkbox laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

How I can check the checked property of a checkbox laravel 4, I try

```
 checkbox =>{{Form::checkbox('same_as_billing', false)}}

 @if(same_as_billing==true)

  ...
 @endif
```

But doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

It's the third parameter:

```
{{Form::checkbox('same_as_billing', 1, true)}}
```

Second parameter is the value, which defaults to 1.